# Nodejs. Events и постороение алгоритмов

Tags: node.js, инспекция-кода, события

Есть необходимость написать консольную утилиту которая в зависимости от выбора пользователя будет запускать определенный алгоритм. Алгоритм нужно сделать модульным, состоящим из заданного перечня задач. Задачи хочу реализовать в виде отдельных класов-модулей которые будут связаны между собой событийной моделью. Простенький пример ниже

```
// main.js
'use strict';
const EventEmitter = require('events');
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

let _first = require('./first');
let _second = require('./second');
let map = new Map();

map.set('first', new _first(myEmitter));
map.set('second', new _second(myEmitter));

myEmitter.emit('start', 3);

// first.js
module.exports = function First(Emiter) {
    Emiter.on('start', (x) => {
      console.log('an event occurred! in First. get: ' + x++);
      Emiter.emit('next', x);
    });
}

// second.js
module.exports = function Second(Emiter) {
    Emiter.on('next', (x) => {
      console.log('an event occurred! in Second, get: ' + x);
    });
}
```

Насколько такой подход юзабелен? Есть ли негативные моменты в обявлении функций обработчиков в конструкторе?